# Outlook 365 Mac, how to ‘nuke’ messages

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript, office365

In outlook 2011 I had an apple script, that would nuke messages, means permanently delete them from any folder in outlook.

I also had a keyboard shortcut assigned to it and so it made dumping spam and other uninteresting stuff really easy without putting them first in the trash and next remove them from the trash.

The script no longer works in 365 (mac version), so I am looking for a new solution.  Does anybody have one?

FYI here is the script I have:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
         set theMsgs to the current messages -- selected messages
         try
                  repeat with theMsg in theMsgs
                           permanently delete theMsg
                  end repeat
         on error errMsg number errNum
                  set theSubject to subject of theMsg
                  set theFolder to name of «class stor» of theMsg
                  beep
                  display dialog errMsg & return & return & errNum & return & return & "(Erroring on message: " & theSubject & " in " & theFolder & ")" with icon 2
         end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi: Your script works for me with Outlook 365 Subscription Version 16.44 on Mojave. I've heard that the latest Outlook is not (yet?) Applescriptable, could you be using that version?

Comment: Thanks, user73082.  I am using V16.45.  However, also had the problem in 16.44 and before that.  As a matter of fact, ever since I changed from Office 2011 to Office 365.
I use OS10.15.7 and am on a MBP Retina. 
So how do you exactly run it when it works for you.  Maybe I do something different?  Would apricate your insight here.

Comment: I simply selected a few messages in Outlook, then switched to your open Applescript in the Script Editor, and ran it.

Comment: wow, that does not work on my end.  nothing happens.  what OS are you on?

Comment: Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: OK Thanks.  I am on 10.15.7.  I tested it on 2 Machines, and it does not work.  
Is there anybody reading with us who could test it please and report back?  I am puzzled indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be the difference between switching to the "New Outlook" look, where the code doesn't work, or staying with the origional Outlook, where it does work.
I am currently using OS 10.15.7 & Version 16.46 Outlook 365 subscription, where the code runs fine under the old outlook look..

cheers

Comment: Hi Budgie.  not sure I understand your answer.  you are on the same OS and Outlook version, correct?  So are you saying it is working fine for you under the OS you name and the version you name or are you saying it runs fie on older versions like 23011?

Comment: shocking explanation by me, sorry, I meant that when you have outlook open, , look top right, an option is displayed to use "New Outlook",  I have found running a few existing scripts using the new option fail, reverting back they run fine, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Morning Budgie, I have no such option on my outlook!  reading a bit about it be searching for >an option is displayed to use "New Outlook",< I find that since I do have my own domain and linked email accounts that this is not supported.  SAo effectively I am, I suppose, on the "Old Outlook"